# CPasswordHelper::hashPassword each time different

Tags: php, yii, authentication

I'm trying to implement login system with Yii Framework.
I followed the official doc :

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPasswordHelper

The thing is the generated hash always change :

```
        $hash =  CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($this->password); // $2a$13$hMiIFbM.D6T98ijK3.Vi1uLWTfKiGddI7ib7iXqb9nztSD.XVsI0e
        $hash2 = CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($this->password); // $2a$13$bDUGC5I8HcQB8XGtY/gXPOzv0KOSkDE.heSMbhD7I1bsvrGEnhV5.
        $hash3 = CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($this->password); // $2a$13$vKilaioNV.vze0v/mrLqaujFg4nDRlRq68GxP/Iyhvz8iQ96witAe

        if(!CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($user->password, $hash)){ // 
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        }
```

Off course, when I try to validate password, it always fails !
Am I missing something???? I fell like the salt is changing each time, but don't know how to do it....

Any Help would be appreciated !

Comment: That's how `hashPassword` works.  It's different every time you do it.  It uses a new, random salt each time it hashes the password.  This is the correct behavior.

Comment: Yes, I was reading it in : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/50590-user-authentication/    . But so, why is my autentication always fail???

Comment: What the difference between `$user->password` and `$this->password`?  What does `CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($this->password, $hash)` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how salted hashes work - the salt is always different, so the hash is always different. The salt is included in the resulting hash, and this library knows how to extract the salt from the hash so it can regenerate the same hash.

Although you haven't made clear where `$this->password` and `$user->password` came from, you should use the raw unhashed password entered by the user as the first argument. I'm guessing that `$user->password` is the hashed version out of the database, and you should pass that as the second argument.

When verifying as password, you don't need to do any hashing yourself.

Putting that all together (if my psychic powers are working :-) ...

```
CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($this->password, $user->password)
```

Comment: You're right, first param should be the clear one, it is not correct to hash it manually before ! Tx !